# Are there any inverse distribution graph that looks like this?

Tags: distributions, quantiles

I want to generate random numbers according to a distribution curve like the [inverse cummulative normal curve](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/excel-help/norm-s-inv-function-HP010335692.aspx). But the curve should allow parameters to adjust the parameters as shown in the image, namely, the slopes (A, B, C), min and max values, between 0.0 and 1.0 in a meaningful manner like in terms of variance, mean etc. the usual stuff.

Is there a well known solution for this curve in terms of statistical distribution?

[image: Inverse Distribution Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to go, I will include some numerical calculations using R.  Suppose you have a continuous random variable $X$, which is real-valued, and have a density $f(x)$ on the interval $[x_\text{min}, x_\text{max}]$.  Then the distribution function $F(x) = \int_{x_\text{min}}^x f(u) \; du $ is continuos and increasing from zero to one on that interval, and the inverse function $Q(p) = F^{-1}(p)$ is also increasing, on the interval $[0, 1]$.

Now use implicit differention on $F(Q(p))=p$ to get $F'(Q(p)) Q'(p)=1$ or
$$
   Q'(p) = \frac1{f(x)}.
$$
This you can use to read some information from your graph: In the area "flat A" the density is high, "growth B" the density is lower, and "taper C" density increases again. This indicates a bimodal distribution!  If you take the interval $x_\text{min}, x_\text{max}$  to be $[0,1]$, you could try to fit some (asymmetric) beta distribution.

To experiment numerically with R, we start to read off some values from your graph.  I do this rather haphazardly, you can redo with more precision.

```
> x
 [1] 0.085 0.090 0.095 0.110 0.150 0.180 0.220 0.250 0.500 0.900 0.980 1.000
> p
 [1] 0.00 0.10 0.20 0.30 0.40 0.50 0.60 0.70 0.80 0.90 0.95 1.00
```

Fit a monotonic spline:

```
> Q  <-  splinefun(p,x,method="monoH.FC")
```

You can plot these function in R.
Then make a more densely populated table, and use it to plot the inverse function $F(x)$:

```
> pp  <-  seq(0,1,by=0.01)
> xx <-  Q(pp)
> plot(xx,pp,type="l")
```

Gives the following plot of the cumulative distribution function:

[image]

You could continue, for example using numerical differentiation to find the density, but that I leave for you.  From this data we can calculate the expextation of $X$, $\mu=\text{E}(X)$.  We use the formula for non-negative random variables
$$
   \mu = \int_0^\infty (1-F(t))\; dt
$$
(which in our case reduces to an integral from zero to one because $1-F(t)$ is zero for $t$ larger than one.)  In R we can approximate this as

> mu <- sum((1-pp))*0.01
>   mu 
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jff1b.jpg) 0.505

When matching to a beta distribution with parameters $a,b$ (refer to wikipedia) we can use then the result that  $\mu = \frac{a}{a+b}$, resulting in the choice $a=1.02 b$, or approximately $a=b$.  Then you can plot beta distributions for various choices of $a$ ($b$) and see if it matches.